# MySQL 8 on Windows 10 - timezone

Tags: mysql, timezone, windows-10, dst, mysql-8.0

I have MySQL 8 running on Windows 10.
The default TimeZone configuration of MySQL 8 ('SYSTEM') isn't suitable with my Windows 10 locale (ITALY), because the system locale (an italian string) isn't recognized from MYSQL.
So I edited my.ini file adding:

```
default-time-zone="+01.00"
```

Everything seemed ok, until march 29th. In that morning Italy adopts daylight savings time, moving TimeZone from +1:00 to +2:00.
This oblige me to set accordingly the my.ini timezone config value 2 times per year. On Saturday night.

Trying to avoid this behavior **I populated the mysql timezone tables** and setting the GLOBAL time_zone var to 'Europe/Rome' I got a satisfied result. 
By the way at db/system restart I lost this value.
I tried to set this in my.ini as:

```
default-time-zone="Europe/Rome"
```

but seems this field can't recognize the values different from time values (and so can't get automatically CET/CEST variation).

At the moment I solved it by executing a delayed script at windows startup running the SET GLOBAL time_zone query, but **I looking for a best practice solution** and, if it's possible, an explanation about the inability of setting unconditionally the default_time_zone property on my.ini config file.

Comment: Have you imported time zones data into `mysql` database? `'Europe/Rome'` is present in it with `Time_zone_id = 465`, and it is successfully recognized.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, when I set the time_zone var as 'Europe/Rome' from SQL it works. But I've to set that var at every restart.

Comment: @Akina as above

Comment: *To explicitly specify the system time zone for MySQL Server at startup, set the TZ environment variable before you start mysqld. If you start the server using mysqld_safe, its --timezone option provides another way to set the system time zone. The permissible values for TZ and --timezone are system dependent. Consult your operating system documentation to see what values are acceptable.*

Comment: @Akina the --timezone option isn't applicable because MySql starts as windows service. I tried already with the SET TZ="Europe/Rome" (with or without quotes) from prompt but it didn't work.

Comment: *I tried already with the SET TZ="Europe/Rome" (with or without quotes) from prompt but it didn't work.* Have you set this variable as user environment variable for the account which is used for MySQL service starting?

Comment: The system has just the domain administrator user. I execute a SET TZ=... command from the prompt. Checked the result with echo %TZ% command. Is it like env variable right?

Comment: When *.ini directives are ignored it can mean three things: 1) Wrong syntax 2) Wrong file 3) Wrong section within file. According to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-variables), #1 is already incorrect (should be `default-time-zone='...'`). Please fix that, restart, and double-check #2 and #3 if problem persists.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález my fault. I reported "_" instead "-". The [mysqld] section of my.ini file contains (copy&paste): default-time-zone='Europe/Rome'. Using this parameter to change as default-time-zone='+05:00' works fine. But I lost CET/CEST feature.